# ASP ADO form not submitting anything and no errors showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to submit a name and country to a database table but the form does not send anything to the db and I'm not getting errors to hint to what is wrong. What am I missing? Thank you.

Model

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets CustomerId.
    ///</summary>
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets Name.
    ///</summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets Country.
    ///</summary>
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action inside HomeController

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CustomerModel customer)
{
    string constr = _config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionString"];
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Customers(Name, Country) VALUES(@Name, @Country)";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", customer.Country);
            
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

From view inside Home view folder

```
@model CustomersADO.Models.CustomerModel;


<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Name">
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="countryInput" class="form-label">Country</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryInput" asp-for="Country">
        <span asp-validation-for="Country" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call one of the Execute methods against the SqlCommand. I would use ExecuteNonQuery as it will return the number of row affected.

```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", customer.Country);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close();
    }
```

[Here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) for that method.